# Use Windows Hello Face recognition without TPM chip

Tags: windows-10, tpm, windows-hello

Is there any possible way to use my IR-Webcamera for windows hello login without a TPM chip on my motherboard?

I had this setup WITH a TPM 2.0 before but something went wrong and the TPM is not recognized any more but aside from that, is it possible?

Comment: AFAIK tpm chip is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, no, since it uses a cryptographic key as a second factor. However, many newer Intel and AMD processors do have a TPM module built into the CPU. You can check if you have one by running `tpm.msc` from the Run command, activated with Win+R.

Comment: Alright, I found something about TXT regarding Intel but couldn't find out if my processor is compatible because there wasn't any guide on Intel's homepage which I could find that said something about the different models and their support for it. I already tried the tpm.msc tool to do some error checking but I guess there is no way around then to buy a new motherboard and a cpu with TXT build in given the bad supply of Mobo's with build in TPM chips.

Comment: @maxpower many boards actually do have TPM headers, so you can buy the chip separately. So maybe you just need to exchange the board, unless you are craving a new cpu.

Comment: I got a mobo with a tpm header but since a fresh new installment of windows 10 nothings works anymore an my tpm chip isn't recognized anymore and the OEM (Asus) has no anser to why and can't help me.. I bought a new TPM and tried it yesterday but it's not getting recognized either.. I downgraded my bios, updated it even.. tried to flash a new firmware onto the tpm and lot's of other changes in my bios but nothing works so my idea was to just upgrade everything and buy a new CPU with TXT, motherboard and ddr4 ram :/ not so funny though for the student budget haha